# Error when checking input: expected input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 1)

Tags: python, keras

This is killing me. Why is it saying input array was (50,1) when its clearly (50,629,160)? I initially thought the Conv1D layers were giving me the trouble but it appears it's in the input layer, right?

```
    # keras.__version__ = 2.2.4
    # X_train.shape = (50,629,160), X_train[0].shape = (629,160)
    # y_train.shape = (50,)

    dim = X_train[0].shape

    input1 = Input(shape=dim,name='input_1')
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', name='conv1', input_shape=dim)(input1)
    maxpool1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, name='maxpool1')(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', name='conv2')(maxpool1)
    maxpool2 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, name='maxpool2')(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', name='conv3')(maxpool2)
    maxpool3 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, name='maxpool3')(conv3)
    flat1 = Flatten(name='flat1')(maxpool3)
    dense1 = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense1')(flat1)
    dense2 = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense2')(dense1)
    output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs=input1,outputs=output1)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train, epochs=30, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=32)
```

And the error code:

```
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 1)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace instead of just that single error line?

Comment: Not sure about your data, but seem you are using `dim=X_train[0].shape` instead of `X_train.shape` as input data.

Comment: @LêTưThành As far as I know the shape argument to the Input layer is that of a single training example. ie. (629,160) in my case.

Comment: I suspect there is an error in my padding/truncating because I can't reproduce the error with dummy data and the exact keras code from the OP. I'm trying to pad arrays of memmaps so maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: Please check `input_1` shape.

Comment: Turns out the error came farther down the line at a validation stage which I had actually anticipated. Apologies for wasting everyone's time. If anyone reads this, this Keras build code above is perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad that you didn't get killed by it!